# Getting "incomplete startup packet" in PostgreSQL Logs

Tags: postgresql

I have a data ware house(Unix Debian) running on PostgreSQL(Version 11.6) which import the data from 2 remote servers and process them and use it for reporting.Everything seems working fine but in PostgreSQL logs i'm getting the below message very frequently, every second i'm getting this message continuously.

When i searched in google various post says that this can be ignored and this will occur once the postgres service is restarted, but i'm not sure about this.

Why this much of packets/info is getting logged ,literally when i saw the entries in real time this entries are keep on piling up.

So can anyone please help me to identify,

1. What is the cause of this?
2. Is this harmful? or anything to be worried about this?
3. Does the log grows to uncontrollable size because of this?

> ```
> 2019-12-05 13:17:29.930 UTC [24101] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
> 2019-12-05 13:17:30.657 UTC [24102] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
> 2019-12-05 13:17:30.723 UTC [24103] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
> 2019-12-05 13:17:31.004 UTC [24104] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
> 2019-12-05 13:17:31.118 UTC [24105] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
> 2019-12-05 13:17:31.752 UTC [24106] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
> 2019-12-05 13:17:32.285 UTC [24107] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
> 2019-12-05 13:17:32.494 UTC [24108] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
> 2019-12-05 13:17:32.511 UTC [24109] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
> 2019-12-05 13:17:32.513 UTC [24110] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
> 2019-12-05 13:17:33.216 UTC [24111] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
> 2019-12-05 13:17:33.989 UTC [24112] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
> 2019-12-05 13:17:34.950 UTC [24113] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
> 2019-12-05 13:17:35.210 UTC [24114] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
> 2019-12-05 13:17:35.511 UTC [24115] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
> 2019-12-05 13:17:38.839 UTC [24116] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
> 2019-12-05 13:17:39.938 UTC [24117] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
> 2019-12-05 13:17:40.238 UTC [24118] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
> 2019-12-05 13:17:40.686 UTC [24119] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
> 2019-12-05 13:17:40.971 UTC [24120] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
> 2019-12-05 13:17:41.348 UTC [24121] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
> 2019-12-05 13:17:42.006 UTC [24122] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
> 2019-12-05 13:17:42.068 UTC [24123] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
> 2019-12-05 13:17:42.489 UTC [24124] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
> 2019-12-05 13:17:42.622 UTC [24125] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
> 2019-12-05 13:17:42.702 UTC [24126] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
> 2019-12-05 13:17:42.719 UTC [24127] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
> 2019-12-05 13:17:43.325 UTC [24128] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
> 2019-12-05 13:17:44.225 UTC [24129] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
> 2019-12-05 13:17:45.276 UTC [24130] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
> 2019-12-05 13:17:45.444 UTC [24131] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
> 2019-12-05 13:17:45.812 UTC [24132] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
> 2019-12-05 13:17:49.016 UTC [24133] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
> 2019-12-05 13:17:50.044 UTC [24135] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
> 2019-12-05 13:17:50.558 UTC [24136] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
> 2019-12-05 13:17:50.795 UTC [24137] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
> 2019-12-05 13:17:51.135 UTC [24138] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
> 2019-12-05 13:17:51.553 UTC [24139] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
> 2019-12-05 13:17:52.377 UTC [24140] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
> 2019-12-05 13:17:52.698 UTC [24141] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
> 2019-12-05 13:17:52.730 UTC [24142] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
> 2019-12-05 13:17:52.915 UTC [24143] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
> 2019-12-05 13:17:52.944 UTC [24144] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
> 2019-12-05 13:17:53.423 UTC [24145] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
> 2019-12-05 13:17:54.440 UTC [24146] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
> 2019-12-05 13:17:55.524 UTC [24147] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
> 2019-12-05 13:17:55.666 UTC [24148] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
> 2019-12-05 13:17:56.097 UTC [24149] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
> ```

Thanks

Comment: Incomplete startup packet means that the client made a connection but did not send any further data i.e. login credentials. This has been removed in postgresql 12 because this behaviour should mostly be harmless. What it could be? An uptime logger, or a portscan - you'll need to do a little more digging to find out what it actually is.

Comment: In fact there was a recent blog on this very subject - https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/12/03/postgresql-12-improvement-benign-log-entries-incomplete-startup-packet/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This very likely a monitoring program or something similar that regularly tests if it can open a TCP connection to the database server.

The messages are harmless and can be ignored. PostgreSQL v13 [won't output these messages any more](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=342cb650e0ffc7a007a12a419be04d47da4bd8cc).